# AWS pulling 2 private git repos via SSH

Tags: python, git, amazon-web-services, github, ssh

I have an EC2 instance that needs two private git repos to run my app. Currently, I have my python app grabbing one repo with SSH (public key is on server and added as a deploy key on github). Problem is I cant use the same public key as the other Deploy Key - github requires unique deploy keys. How can I configure the ec2 instance to use to key pairs or perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score -1):

You could generate a personal access token for your git hub account that would act like a password.

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

You can generate as many of these as you like and when you create it you can limit the scope of what the token allows the holder to do.

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes

You can then clone your repo using HTTPS,

https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-recommended